# Installing R from CRAN Ubuntu repository: No Public Key Error

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, ssh, gnupg, keys

any advice for the following, after being here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255082/installing-r-from-cran-ubuntu-repository-no-public-key-error ?

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver key-server.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.mDoibc6YYl/gpg.1.sh --keyserver key-server.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name

Comment: You only need the last 8 characters of the key when you are adding it.  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9` worked for me.

Comment: Much appreciated.. hours of other errors and fails limit one's drive to 'try'.. gpg: imported: 1.. :)

Comment: Did you misspell the server name? afaik it's `keyserver.ubuntu.com` not `key-server.ubuntu.com`

Comment: @steeldriver Ooops, I missed that part!  I am so used to it not having a - in it that I totally missed that part of it.  Good thing my comment didn't have the - in it.  Good eye!  =)